# Pushforward of a measure using a conjugacy

Tags: differential-topology, dynamical-systems

Suppose $\eta$ is a continuous function with a continuous inverse on the circle $S^1$ such that it behaves as a conjugacy between two maps $T_1:S^1 \to S^1$ and $T_2: S^1 \to S^1$. That is, $\eta \circ T_1 \circ \eta^{-1} = T_2$.

A conjecture is if for a set $A$, $\lambda(\eta(A)) = 1$, then, $(\eta)_*\lambda = \lambda$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. I can see that this is not true for a generic continuous
function $\eta$ because the Lebesgue measure of any subset is not the same as the Lebesgue measure of the range of the subset under $\eta$, in general. I am wondering if there is something special about conjugacies which might make this conjecture true.

Thank you very much for your time!

EDIT: Here is some context for this question. I am interested in the Lebesgue measure of a certain nice set. The nice set $N$ is the set of all points 
in $S^1$ for which Birkhoff averages under $T_1$ converge to expected values
wrt to a certain measure (that happens to be Lebesgue) that is invariant under both $T_1$ and $T_2$ and is the SRB measure of $T_2$. What I really want is to find necessary and sufficient conditions for the Lebesgue measure of $N$ to be 1. Now if the conjugacy did not preserve the Lebesgue measure, then, I know that my nice set automatically has measure 0 (since it can only have measure 0 or 1). On the other hand, if $\lambda(N)= 1$, does it imply that $\eta$ preserves $\lambda$ ?(this was the conjecture in the question).

Comment: You really should not expect that conjugacies are measure-preserving, they simply relate different dynamics. But in certain classes of hyperbolic systems one can have something quite similar in the holonomies, with bounded Jacobian. It seems to me that it is (very!) difficult to say much more. On the other hand, I wonder whether it would be interesting. Could you perhaps detail the context of your question?

Comment: Wow, thank you very much @JohnB! I am going to edit my question to add some context.

Comment: Perhaps I don't quite follow, but since you say that $T_1$ preserves Lebesgue measure shouldn't you instead look for conditions on the ergodicity of $\lambda$? Or instead you should really show that the Jacobian is well defined (and so since zero measure sets go to zero measure sets, full measure sets would go to full measure sets, under nice conditions).

Comment: Do you mean the Jacobian of $\eta$? I don't have a differentiable conjugacy.

Comment: Well yes, I didn't know if this was the case or not. :(